# GreenDao insert, insertOrReplace, save

Tags: android, orm, greendao

Can somebody explain me what is difference between methods `insert`, `insertOrReplace` and `save` in **GreenDao** library?

I understand that the `insert` does just inserting and `insertOrReplace` inserts if does not exist or updates/replaces if exists.

But it is confusing how `insertOrReplace` and `save` differs?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `insert()` adds Entity into Table, assumes Entity with that Key does not exist. If exists, it shall throw Exception
- `insertOrReplace()` adds Entity into Table if Key does not exist, replaces if Key exists.
- [save()](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/521#issuecomment-309757364) adds Entity which has no Key into Table, updates if it has Key and Entity exists on Table. If Entity has Key and does not exist on Table, it will do nothing.

Comment: I got "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported for entities with a non-null key" with **save**, but not with **insertOrReplace()**

Answer (score 1):

From the [`Javadoc`](http://greenrobot.org/files/greendao/javadoc/current/org/greenrobot/greendao/AbstractDao.html#save-T-) for `AbstractDao.java`

```
"Save 'saves' an entity to the database: depending on the existence of the key 
property, it will be inserted (key is null) or updated (key is not null). 
This is similar to insertOrReplace, but may be more efficient, because if 
a key is present, it does not have to query if that key already exists."
```

From looking at the code for the `save` method, it contains an `if` statement on the `haskey` method to determine if to run an `update` or `insert`:

```
if (hasKey(entity)) {
    update(entity);
} else {
    insert(entity);
}
```

Whereas `insertOrReplace` executes an actual `INSERT OR REPLACE` sql statement.

Comment: Please help me to understand what is going on. If I have empty table and use `saveInTx` method non of records are wrote to DB. If I use `inserOrReplaceInTx` then records are wrote. What is wrong with this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more information about the DB `entity` and what you are trying to save. Have you tried enabling logging on the `dao` to see the debug output?

    `dao.queryBuilder().LOG_VALUES=true;`

    `dao.queryBuilder().LOG_SQL=true;`

Comment: Entity is pretty simple, it has a few fields (id, name) and list of objects of another entity.
Also I have observed that in one table I have multiple records of the same data either I use `saveInTx` or `InsertOrReplaceInTx`.
I didn't menage to enable logging, I have used 
        `QueryBuilder.LOG_SQL = true;
        QueryBuilder.LOG_VALUES = true;`